# how to access node_module directory which was out side the static content serving folder

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express, node-modules

need to access node_module directory files from the index.html file which was inside a sub directories and the node_module directory is in the same location of parent directory. Here i'm using angularjs and the static folder to server files is the public directory.

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

Directory structure is provided in the screenshot.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ykbza.png)

Answer (score 1):

try this for node_modules folder also

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules'));
```

and then in index.html you can directly access sub directories of node_modules folder for eg.

```
<script src="async/component.json"></script>
```

Comment: app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/node_modules')); cant use this, just because we need to access the static pages inside the public folder. its not in the node_module folder.

Comment: @JaisonAbraham You don't replace the "/public" line, you create a new line that looks similar but for the /node_modules directory.

Comment: @JaisonAbraham i meant to add another line for node_modules folder like that of the public folder .... not replacing the public folder line ...